# Is there any usable GPU based constraint solver? CUDA, OpenCL?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, constraint-programming

I am looking for a usable GPU based constraint solver for solving constrained timetables for schools. The constraint problem is course timetabling.

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#curriculumCourse

JaCoP is another constraint solver https://github.com/radsz/jacop

Comment: Can't you use a multithreaded or OpenMP library doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of such already available solver.

**But:**
[Satisfiability solvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) can be used to solve timetable problems as discussed in this [dissertation](http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/sat/theses/kenneth.pdf).

The [CUD@SAT](http://clp.dimi.uniud.it/sw/cudasat/) project demonstrates how to solve SAT problems using [NVIDIA CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) architecture.
It might be instructive to use the search facility of [hpgu.org](http://hgpu.org/?p=12506&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20hgpuorg%20%28High%20performance%20computing%20on%20Graphics%20Processing%20Units%29). It is fully devoted to such projects.